# How the child div cover the full width of the parent div in Bootstrap without using positioning?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a child div within the Bootstrap container div. How can the child div cover the full width of the parent ?

```
<div class="container">
     <div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-12 parent">
             <div class="Full-Width"></div>
         </div>
     </div>
  </div>
```

How to make this .Full-Width div width 100% of it's parent div ?

Answer (score 2):

Bootstrap gives `padding` for some elements by default. So you have to add custom class to those elements and set `padding` to 0.

http://jsfiddle.net/732a8rmp/

Answer (score 2):

Bootstrap 4 you can use w-100 class.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 parent">
            <div class="w-100"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Reference: [https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/sizing/][1]

Answer (score 1):

Umm, you should probably re-word your question because as it sits right now,

**this css:** `.Full-Width{width: 100%;}` answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

**CSS**

```
.Full-Width {
    display: block
}
```

This can also be done using:

```
.Full-Width {
    width: 100%
}
```